# Conflicts between with click function

Tags: jquery, function, click

I have some problems on conflicting code, I've checked my console for any errors, but so far nothing, basically have several selections with notifications via jGrowl.

Im using jQuery 1.9.1

This is the first part

```
                $("#amconf-images-139.amconf-images-container").click(function() {
        if ($('#amconf-image-84.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){
            var a = $('input[name="qty2"]').val().replace("$", ""); 
            var b = $('#product-price-1202_clone span.price').html().replace("$", "");  
            $.jGrowl("1 inch Debossed Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a*b).toFixed(2));
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-86.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("1 inch Ink-Injected Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a*b).toFixed(2));
             } else if ($('#amconf-image-87.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("1 inch Printed Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a*b).toFixed(2));
        } 
});
```

The code above works but then it kills the second part

```
       $("#amconf-images-140").click(function() {
        if ($('#amconf-image-114.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){
            $.jGrowl("Black Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-115.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Brown Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-116.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Green Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-117.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Grey Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-118.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Hot Pink Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-119.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Hunter Green Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-120.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Lavender Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-121.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Light Blue Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-122.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Light Pink Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-123.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Lime Green Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-124.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Maroon Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-125.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Metallic Gold Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-126.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Metallic Silver Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-127.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Olive Green Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-128.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Orange Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-129.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Pearl Blue Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-130.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Purple Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-131.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Red Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-132.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Reflex Blue Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-133.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Teal Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-134.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("White Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-135.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Yellow Color Selected");
        } else if ($('#amconf-image-136.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length){      
            $.jGrowl("Yellow Gold Color Selected");
        } 
     });
```

The second jquery part doesn't want to show the notification, could it be the divs are too similar? They are completely seperate divs with their own unique number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sea of _else if_ statements, your code needs a review.

Comment: Please don't write code like this. It is much less error prone if you just write a lookup table like this: ``{'114': 'Black', '115': 'Brown', ...}`` and then just look up in that table in stead of all those ``if`` statements.

Comment: I was not aware of that, which is why im here! How would i got about it with jGrowl in the mix?

Comment: Did you try to step through the code with a debugger? I can recommend the one built into Chrome.

Comment: @mzedeler yeah i did, im using chrome's console and selected over the DEBUG and also checked it on ALL after, but so far nothing.

Comment: So you set a breakpoint inside the click handler and saw it execute one of the ``$.jGrowl...`` statements?

Comment: In that first code, `a` and `b` are used out of scope;

Comment: @mzedeler yeah basically for that specific div class when found, it would execute a jGrowl notification. Im looking into table values, just looking where to start with that since it looks wayyy more efficient

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started:

```
var amimages140 = {
    "114": "Black Color Selected",
        "115": "Brown Color Selected",
        "116": "Green Color Selected",
        "117": "Grey Color Selected",
        "118": "Hot Pink Color Selected",
        "119": "Hunter Green Color Selected",
        "120": "Lavender Color Selected",
        "121": "Light Blue Color Selected",
        "122": "Light Pink Color Selected",
        "123": "Lime Green Color Selected",
        "124": "Maroon Color Selected",
        "125": "Metallic Gold Color Selected",
        "126": "Metallic Silver Color Selected",
        "127": "Olive Green Color Selected",
        "128": "Orange Color Selected",
        "129": "Pearl Blue Color Selected",
        "130": "Purple Color Selected",
        "131": "Red Color Selected",
        "132": "Reflex Blue Color Selected",
        "133": "Teal Color Selected",
        "134": "White Color Selected",
        "135": "Yellow Color Selected",
        "136": "Yellow Gold Color Selected"
};
```

Fix scope issue:

```
$("#amconf-images-139.amconf-images-container").click(function () {
    var a = '';
    var b = '';
    if ($('#amconf-image-84.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length) {
        a = $('input[name="qty2"]').val().replace("$", "");
        b = $('#product-price-1202_clone span.price').html().replace("$", "");
        $.jGrowl("1 inch Debossed Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a * b).toFixed(2));
    } else if ($('#amconf-image-86.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length) {
        $.jGrowl("1 inch Ink-Injected Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a * b).toFixed(2));
    } else if ($('#amconf-image-87.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length) {
        $.jGrowl("1 inch Printed Selected<br />Estimated Cost: $" + (a * b).toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Simpler method:

```
$("#amconf-images-140").click(function () {
    var im = '';
    for (im in amimages140) {
        if ($('#amconf-image-' + im + '.amconf-image.amconf-image-selected').length) {
            $.jGrowl(amimages140[im]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You sir Mark, are f****** amazing!

Comment: That first method needs work similar to the second.  I will leave that up to you. - note without layout difficult to tell if you need to stop propagation of the click events.